# Beamer poster citations at wrong place due to use of minipage

Tags: beamer, citing, beamerposter

I want to add a couple citations to my poster but I face a problem regarding the place where the citations appear.

In the code that follows (minimum example which for some reason I cannot understand to be honest gives an error but outputs a pdf file nevertheless) what I want is to make the citations appear in the end of the page. On the contrary they appear right after the next tabular environment (or after the next tikzpicture in my full poster) as you can see in the following picture.

[image]

I have to mention that I'm using the `beamerthemeI6pd2` style. I would love to know why this happens and how to solve it since I do not have much experience in latex, yet I love it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{I6pd2}}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a4,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}


\newlength{\columnheight}
\setlength{\columnheight}{25cm}
\fontsize{9}{10}
\selectfont
\bibliography{test3}
\graphicspath{{pix/}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{columns}
    % ---------------------------------------------------------%
    % Set up a column 
    \begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
            \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}
                \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                        this is some test text \footfullcite{osborne-rubinstein}
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                        this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                        this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                        this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                        \begin{tabular}{lc}
                                    \begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
                                        \begin{algorithmic}[0]
                                            \ForAll{attacker distributions}
                                            \ForAll{combinations of $z$,$t$,$F_z$ and $\sigma^2_z$}
                                            \State calculate payoff
                                            \State locate saddle points
                                            \EndFor
                                            \EndFor
                                        \end{algorithmic} 
                                    \end{minipage}&
                                    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
                            \textbf{Why simulations?}
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item cheap
                            \item fast
                            \item flexible
                        \end{itemize}
                        \end{minipage} \\
                            \end{tabular}
            \end{block}
            \begin{block}{Test}
                this is some test text
            \end{block}
            \begin{block}{Test}
                this is some test text
            \end{block}
            \begin{block}{Test}
                this is some test text
            \end{block}
        }
    \end{minipage}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{column}
    % Second Column %
    \begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
            \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}
                \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                    \begin{block}{Test}
                      this is some test text
                    \end{block}
                }
            \end{minipage}
        \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

After a few test I narrowed down the problem. It seems that using the `minipage` tag confuses the `cite` command when it comes to the location of the citing. Anyone has a clue why this happen and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that `\footfullcite` uses `\footnote` and, when used inside `minipage`s/`column`s, `\footnote` causes the footnote/cite to appear immediatly after the `minipage`/`column` and not at the bottom of the page/frame; you can solve this using `\footnotemark` at the place of the citation in the document, and then `\footnotecite` *outside* the `minipage`/`column`, sice `\footnotecite` uses `\footnotemark` instead of `\footnote`.

A little example (I suppressed most of the code used in the original question that wasn't relevant for the problem and its solution):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
\begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}
  \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
\begin{block}{Test}
this is some test text\footnotemark
\end{block}}
\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}\footcitetext{osborne-rubinstein}
%Second Column %
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
test
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On a side note, you mentioned en error you cannot explain. The theme you are using requires to provide at least `\author` and `\institution` (otherwise an error is produced) and to have available certain image; in your minimal example none of those factors are taken into account so that might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: using `\footnotecite` means that the reference has to be manually written here. Is there any `biblatex` command to be used for this purpose that also uses `\footnotemark`. I could not figure that out. Or does it mean that if you use `\column` and there is a reference in such environment is mandatory to manually write this reference?

Comment: `\footnotetext{\fullcite{citeKey}}` makes the trick.